# How to enable enter button on keyboard on wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was noticing on certain application for wp7, that they were able to use the enter key on the keyboard to submit, but by default when you hit the enter key it goes to the next line. I was even noticing the enter key is different from the default enter key.

How do you submit, and if possible how do you change the way the enter key looks?

Any tips, answers or resources would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `InputScope` from "Text" and then capture the enter key on the KeyDown event.

Comment: Why does he have to change the `InputScope`? Is that necessary for catching the `KeyDown` event?

Comment: This works perfect. 
@Praetorian The InputScope changes the visual look of the "enter" key. But to detect the enter key was pressed you have to use the "KeyDown" event.

Comment: @loyalpenguin: Got it, I hadn't read your question completely and missed the part where you asked about the visual style.

Answer (score 3):

As Matt states, the keyboard layout depends on the `InputScope` that you specify. You can find some illustrations of the different layouts on [Jeff Blankenburg's blog](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-10-InputScope-TextBoxes.aspx).

If you're interested in using the Enter key to "tab" between input fields, there's a great [behavior](http://pauliom.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/wp7-keyboard-helper-as-a-behavior/) you can use.

Comment: This is a great resource. Excellent Find.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems more standard (on a touch device) to trigger a submit/enter on the up/release. One benefit being, if you press on an adjacent key to the one intended, you can then drag over to it and release.